# How to detect pause button click in mediaelement?

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

I am trying to detect click event on mediaelement pause button

http://jsfiddle.net/wLu2v/9/

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('.player_1');

$('body').on('click', '.mejs-pause', function (e) {
    $('.items').append('<li>paused</li>');
});
```

I also tried with `mejs-pause button` and few other combos but cant detect the event . 
Any help is appreciated

Comment: I was just looking at some other posts online and looks like the Play/Pause button is actually a button inside of a div which is styled with the class .mejs-pause.   You might try $("button[title='Play/Pause']").  However, if you have multiple Play/Pause buttons on your screen you'll get them all.

Comment: $("button[title='Play/Pause']").on("click", function (e) {
    console.log("111");
    $('.items').append('<li>paused</li>');
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an `event` listener to MEJS initialization script on `success` setting like :

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('.player_1', {
    success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
        mediaElement.addEventListener('pause', function () {
            // do something here
            $('.items').append('<li>paused</li>');
        }, false);
    }
});
```

See your forked **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2we22/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this, tested as of march 2020 with latest mediaelement.js

```
$('audio').mediaelementplayer({
    pluginPath: 'https://cdnjs.com/libraries/mediaelement/',
    shimScriptAccess: 'always',
    success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
        mediaElement.addEventListener('play', function () {
          var aid = $(domObject).closest(".mejs__container").attr('id');
          document.getElementById(aid).getElementsByClassName("mejs__time-rail")[0].style.display = "block";
        }, false);
    }
  });
```